# Post this $ajax request to REST API

Tags: ajax, api, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I have this ajax POST code, which works directly on browser, but when i want to make a POST using the same data on Fiddler or SoapUI or using httpClient or HttpWebPost it doesn't work, always returns ERRROR. Below are the Ajax code and Fiddler. Thank you in advance.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://IP/address/post/something",
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
dataType: "text",

data:
{ message: 'testMessage', destination: '8888888888', campaign: 'UATTest', agent: 'TestingAgent'}
,
success: function (resp) {
if (resp != "ERROR") {
} else {
}
},
error: function (e) {
}
});
```

[image]

Update :

Does anybody know how to consume a REST API using FormParam ? how is it differ from JSON and XML ?

params:
@FormParam("destination"), @FormParam("message"), @FormParam("campaign"), @FormParam("agent")

Comment: What's the actual error?  If the server is returning the string "ERROR" with a *successful* status code then that's a bit misleading.  More to the point, unless the server is actually telling you what's wrong then how can we possibly know how to fix it?

Comment: Hi David you are right, 200 OK status, but ERRROR, that's the only thing the server returned, maybe i am missing something =( on Fiddler i got error code 500

Comment: You're going to have to find out from the server what the actual problem is.  If it's something you control, you will need to debug it.  If it's not something you control, you will need to contact whoever does control it.  The response is giving you two conflicting pieces of information, one indicating success and one indicating failure.  And the latter isn't telling you anything about *why* it might have failed.

Comment: Actaully i fixed the contentType to content-Type, now my Fiddler is returning 200 OK, but still not working and getting the ERRROR messsage.

Comment: Just contacted the developer, they actually use FormParams  instead of JSON to make POST request, anybody has any idea about how to post FormParams using fiddler or any other tools ?